Are winged characters still prohibited in Adventurers League, as of April 2024?
I was reading through the Adventurers League Player's Guide v14.0, and I noticed that I couldn't find any mention of flying characters being banned. Does this mean that flying PC races are allowed now?
I've seen various other questions asking the same thing, but they seem to reference outdated documents:

From September 2017: Is playing an Aarakocra player character currently legal in Adventurers League, as of September 2017?
From March 2016: Is the flight that a variant Tiefling (SCAG) has game breaking? (specifically, Adeptus' answer)


As of Version 14.0 of the DDAL Player's Guide (available from the collected resources page), there is no blanket prohibition against flying characters.
However, there are some campaign-specific† concerns to keep in mind. Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide (where the Winged Tiefling variant is published) is only available to characters in the Forgotten Realms campaign. Characters in the Eberron, Ravenloft, Dragonlance, and Planescape campaigns do not have access to SCAG and cannot be Winged Tieflings.
Note that AL does require using the most recent published version of something - while Elemental Evil Player's Companion (and where Aarakocra were first published) is a valid source for all DDAL campaigns, you have to use the version printed in Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiverse.
†I don't own the additional source material for the other campaigns, so don't know if they add any campaign-specific flying race options.

Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos has the Owlin race, but I'm not sure if that is allowed in any AL campaigns.

@User23415 It is not.

It would appear not.
I went through every linked document in the new official Adventurer's League resources location on DNDBeyond, and none of them listed any sort of restriction against flight.
